# Unable to set SPN for microsoft SQL Server: Insufficient access rights to perform the operation

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to set a spn using PowerShell for my service account. But I receive "error 0x2098/8344 -> Insufficient access rights to perform the operation"

All results point me towards adding allow on Read/Write ServicePrincipalName (image 2) which I have set. Is there some other permission I am lacking?

[image: SPN Fails]
[image: ServicePrincipalName]

Answer (score 1):

we normally use Kerberos manager for sql server to generate the spn commands and then get a domain admin user to run.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/using-kerberosmngr-sqlserver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).